# retrieving actual bank statements

Tags: yodlee

Does yodlee provide any means for retrieving an actual bank statement (like a pdf) vs. the data contained in this statement? Due to some regulatory requirements, our intended users would need to confirm that statement information provided is complete. Currently this is done by asking for a complete statement from the banks' website, like a pdf print out. Does yodlee have any apis that could return statements unmodified vs the transactions and other information from the statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yodlee provides APIs to retrieve the transactions & other statement related information like Amount Due, Due Date etc , while there is no such API which will provide you complete Statement in PDF format(As you receive from Bank itself).

Comment: How to pass the authorization header to the ysl apis

Answer (score 0):

So far I know Yodlee only provides transactions, you may create your statements by filtering for the specific periods. Yodlee does not download any statements but it get its transactions by screen scrapping method. So you'll receive transactions and then it is up to you to handle them according to your business needs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually fairly familiar with yodlee. (I implemented multiple systems using it over the years. They do have specific calls to get very detailed statement information.) I just need a definite answer from someone who knows all of their services and apis if this is possible. Possibly from someone at yodlee...